# Enum with switch

Tags: java

I have an enum and I need to bind these values to the switch in another class, Help please, I'm confused

```
public enum GSProccesingType {
    bigCover,
    cover,
    other
}

class Test {
 switch (GSProccesingType){
        case bigCover:
        break;
        case cover:
            break;
        case default:
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: what's the confusion ?

Comment: Switch takes a value expression, not a type even for the num.

Comment: 1) You can't have raw statements in a class declaration; they need to be in a method or an initialization block. 2) You have to `switch` on a value, not on a type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836286/enums-use-in-switch-case?rq=1 maybe this works for you

Comment: `case default:` is also a syntax error. Did you mean `default:` or `case other:`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391791/4848659 can find exact answer you need here. You need an instace to be created and then, used.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: enums are considered constants and thus should be written down in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Comment: Besides, when you write down your switch statement like that, what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an object first. Then use that object in switch statement. Like below:

```
GSProccesingType type = GSProccesingType.cover;.   // type will hold any one of the enum values. Cover is one such value
switch(type){...}
```

For your example you need to put `bigCover` in switch

Comment: why .cover if i have in enum 3 values: bigCover, cover and other?

Comment: It's an example. The object will hold any one of the enum values

Comment: I can not understand .cover And what is this?

Comment: For your case bigCover holds the value of the enum. Put that variable in the switch.

Comment: @TerletskiyAlexander Perfect example, when you don't read the topic completely and directly jumped into implementation.You should first understand `what is ENUM`

Comment: @TerletskiyAlexander are you coding with C before? In C language, you can get the enum value right away. But with Java, you need to get first the enum parent GSProccessingType. Also you need a non-constant expression when passing to switch statement. For example `GSProccesingType yourExpression; yourExpression = GSProccesingType (dot) (your selected enum); switch ( yourExpression){ case GSProccesingType.bigCover: break; case GSProccesingType.cover: break; case GSProccesingType.other: break; case default: ;}`